# Register or Registration For a B2B Sign page

Tags: registration, copywriting, signup, register

I want to assess the use of the word `Registration` vs `Register` on sign up pages. Is there a consensus or research done on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about such research, but from my knowledge there are a few things that are well-known:

1. For buttons, you should use verbs, so "Register" in this case.
2. For labels, you should use descriptive nouns, so "Registration" in this case.
3. For content or other types of app copy, the specific words don't matter that much as long as they are clearly understood by your target audience. It's usually best to speak the language of your audience, so check similar popular products in your niche and design your content similar to them, because that's what your users will expect.

Comment: Thanks, is there any particular research you are referencing  that labels are to be descriptive nouns?

Comment: Not one that I know, it's just common practice in the industry.